# ADF Taskflow reset

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

In ADF, how to restart a taskflow region. I have a jsf page consisting of command links on one side and a region on the other. The region is always the same taskflow but I need to restart the taskflow back to defaut activity on click of any command link. RefreshCondition and refresh ifNeeded properties did not reset the task flow activity. Thanks.

Comment: Show some code -- what does the `adfc-config` look like (a screen capture would help)? If you can simplify the use case that would also help solve the problem. Also, post a bit of the code showing the command links; you don't have to post the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

Using the TF itself:
http://andrejusb.blogspot.be/2011/08/adf-dialog-framework-and-adf-task-flow.html
Using code in your backing bean:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1013471

Answer (score 0):

Have an input parameter for the taskflow,When you want to restart the region, change the value of input parameter.

Comment: any example how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option for acheving this:-
1. Create a dynamic region
2. Create a bounded taskflow with a single blank page (used for reset) and add to the dynamic region as default region
3. add other taskflows as you need and add command links to the left side
4. Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

add a "control flow" in your task flow starting and ending at same page. give some name to that "control flow".Suppose the value is "back" Now on every command link action pass that value.   eg: .

//this would work.Let me know what happens